# Laravel Maatwebsite/excel adding data in extra columns randomly

Tags: php, excel, laravel

I am building an excel file using maatwebsite/excel in Laravel. However it seems to be adding data across the rows not in the way I expect it to. Am I missing something that might be causing this? Its not consistent either, e.g. for new sheets it's adding literally that same data even though the sheet may have different figures on the left.

[image]

As a workaround I have had to add a bunch of empty cells to each row like so...

```
                $sheet->row( 1, array(
                    'From: '.$from_date,
                    'To: '.$to_date,
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    ''
                ) );
```

My code without the workaround:

```
    $rows[$product_type] = array (
        'Received'              => $received,
        'Visually Inspected'    => $visually_inspected,
        'Visually Passed'       => $visually_passed,
        'Visually Failed'       => $visually_failed,
        'Technically Inspected' => $technically_inspected,
        'Technically Passed'    => $technically_passed,
        'Technically Failed Phase 1' => $technically_failed_1,
        'Technically Failed Phase 2' => $technically_failed_2,
        'Technically Failed Phase 3' => $technically_failed_3,
        'Total Technically Failed'    => $failed
    );
    Excel::create( 'KGdfmg564fdsin4', function ( $excel ) use ( $rows, $product_types, $to_date, $from_date) {

        // Set the title
        $excel->setTitle( 'Company Dashboard Report Data' );

        // Chain the setters
        $excel->setCreator( 'Company ' )
              ->setCompany( 'Company ' );
        foreach($product_types as $key => $val) {
            $excel->sheet( $key, function ( $sheet ) use ( $rows, $key, $to_date, $from_date ) {

                $sheet->fromArray( $rows );
                $sheet->setWidth( array(
                    'A' => 50,
                    'B' => 50
                ) );
                $sheet->row( 1, array(
                    'From: '.$from_date,
                    'To: '.$to_date,

                ) );
                $sheet->row( 2, array(
                    'Received',
                    $rows[$key]['Received'],

                ) );
                $sheet->row( 3, array(
                    'Visually Inspected',
                    $rows[$key]['Visually Inspected'],
                ) );
                $sheet->row( 4, array(
                    'Visually Passed',
                    $rows[$key]['Visually Passed'],
                ) );
                $sheet->row( 5, array(
                    'Visually Failed',
                    $rows[$key]['Visually Failed'],
                ) );
                $sheet->row( 6, array(
                    'Technically Inspected',
                    $rows[$key]['Technically Inspected'],
                ) );
                $sheet->row( 7, array(
                    'Technically Passed',
                    $rows[$key]['Technically Passed'],
                ) );
                $sheet->row( 8, array(
                    'Technically Failed Phase 1',
                    $rows[$key]['Technically Failed Phase 1'],
                ) );
                $sheet->row( 9, array(
                    'Technically Failed Phase 2',
                    $rows[$key]['Technically Failed Phase 2'],
                ) );
                $sheet->row( 10, array(
                    'Technically Failed Phase 3',
                    $rows[$key]['Technically Failed Phase 3'],
                ) );
                $sheet->row( 11, array(
                    'Units Technically Failed',
                    $rows[$key]['Total Technically Failed'],
                ) );


            } );
        }

        // Call them separately
        $excel->setDescription( 'Dashboard Report Data' );

    } )->save( 'xlsx' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `$sheet->fromArray( $rows );` from your code works for me give it a try.

[image]